# Qm error: ListElement Invalid property name Qt5.15.1 & module versions

Tags: qt, qml

I have issues with >=Qt5.15.0 regarding code check, therefore I updated to Qt5.15.1.
I don't have the issue with Qt5.12.9.

```
Qt Version: 5.15.1
QtCreator Version: 4.13
Compiler: MinGW-64Bit
OS: Windows 10
```

Based on the example for Qt5.15.1 about Listmodel I used follwoing code:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQml.Models 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListView {
         anchors.fill: parent
         model: fruitModel
         delegate: Row {
             Text { text: "Fruit: " + name }
             Text { text: "Cost: $" + cost }
         }
     }


    ListModel {
         id: fruitModel

         ListElement {
             name: "Apple"
             cost: 2.45
         }
         ListElement {
             name: "Orange"
             cost: 3.25
         }
         ListElement {
             name: "Banana"
             cost: 1.95
         }
     }
}
```

I get errors for the ListElements **Invalid property name "name". (M16)** and **Invalid property name "cost". (M16)**, but the application compiles and works. I added import statement
`import QtQml.models 2.15`, which was not required for Qt5.12.9, but still error occurs.

What I recognized is during import statement version code completion the ComboBox latest version is .12 not .15

**Questions:**

1. Why I get this errors?
2. Why the code completion ComboxBox doesn't show up version *.15 ?

**Remark:**
I recognized this behavior on two PCs with same OS etc and is very annoying to work with wrong issue highlight

Comment: In the past I had similar issues that could be resolved by deleting all contents of the build directory.

Comment: I deleted manualy build folder, but still same. I tried "Clean Project", "Run qmake", "Build Project". If I get no solving answer, then I guess is a bug and create jira ticket, but before I have to ask community, if they see an mistake by me

Answer (score 1):

Is a Bug of Qt-Creator 4.13.0 and is fixed in Qt-Creator 4.13.1. I did not saw the Ticket in QDS Project, because I searched in Qt-Creator and Qt.

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QDS-2602